# Running development server with create-react-app inside of a docker container

Tags: docker, create-react-app

I am trying to run the create-react-app's development server inside of a docker container and have it recompile and send the changed app code to the client for development purposes, but it isn't picking up the changes from inside of the docker container.

(Of course, I have the working directory of the app as a volume for the container.)

Is there a way to do make this work?

Comment: If you are launching with something like `docker run -it --rm -v ${PWD}:/app  -v /app/node_modules -p 3001:3000  -e CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true sample:dev` make sure you use powershell and that the variable interpolation works ( the part with ${} ). I was working with git bash and it was creating some weird folder and the react live reload was not working. Switching to powershell fixed the issues.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Actually, I found an answer [here](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/1049). Apparently create-react-app uses chokidar to watch file changes, and it has a flag CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING to use polling to watch for file changes instead. So `CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true npm start` should fix the problem. As for me, I set `CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true` in my environment variable for the docker container and just started the container.

Comment: This fixes but there is a significant delay for hot reloading and my cpu usage was above 60%

Comment: Yes I agree it isn't the optimal solution. Please post an answer if you've found a better solution.

Comment: See the answer I just added.

Comment: Creating a `.env` file with `CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true` worked for me (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/43281575/470749 and https://create-react-app.dev/docs/troubleshooting/ and https://stackoverflow.com/a/57691204/470749 )

Comment: You can configure webpack to use polling and ignore the `node_modules` while watching. This solves the CPU problem. See the answer for Vue (should be similar for React): https://stackoverflow.com/a/67209565/3233827

Comment: CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING was not working for me, but adding "WATCHPACK_POLLING=true" as environment in my nodejs-instance in docker-compose, helping me, and hot reload works for me, now I don't even have to reload the website, content refreshing automaticle after edit and saving file.

Answer (score 10):

Polling, suggested in the other answer, will cause much higher CPU usage and drain your battery quickly. You should not need `CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true` since file system events should be propagated to the container. Since recently this should work even if your host machine runs Windows: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/release-notes/#docker-desktop-community-2200 (search for "inotify").

However, when using Docker for Mac, this mechanism seems to be failing sometimes: https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/2417#issuecomment-462432314

Restarting the Docker daemon helps in my case.

Answer (score 6):

With react-script v5.0.0 onward the command is `WATCHPACK_POLLING=true` instead of `CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true`

Comment: I am using react-script v5.0.1 on a dockerized react app and when I go with your solution webpack compiles successfully but browser staying still. After compilation I must refresh browser. How can I solve this issue? PS: When I use CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING browser refreshes but changes are not compiled before it.

Answer (score 3):

---

Clear Answer for **react-script v5.0.0** onward

---

1- Create a `.env` file in the root directory of the project

2- Add the `WATCHPACK_POLLING=true` to the `.env` file

3- build new image

4- run new container

5- verify that the changes being detected.

---

Or you can just add `WATCHPACK_POLLING=true` to your script for making the container like this

> `docker run --name my-app -it --rm -v $(pwd)/src:/app/src -p 3000:3000 -e WATCHPACK_POLLING=true myapp`

Comment: I am using react-script v5.0.1 on a dockerized react app and when I go with your solution webpack compiles successfully but browser staying still. After compilation I must refresh browser. How can I solve this issue? PS: When I use CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING browser refreshes but changes are not compiled before it.

Answer (score 2):

If your changes are not being picked up, it is probably a problem with the file watching mechanism. A workaround for this issue is to configure polling. You can do that globally as explained by [@Javascriptonian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44643246/3233827), but you can do this also locally via the webpack configuration. This has the benefit of specifying ignored folders (e.g. `node_modules`) which slow down the watching process (and lead to high CPU usage) when using polling.

In your webpack configuration, add the following configuration:

```
devServer: {
  watchOptions: {
    poll: true, // or use an integer for a check every x milliseconds, e.g. poll: 1000
    ignored: /node_modules/ // otherwise it takes a lot of time to refresh
  }
}
```

*source: [documentation webpack watchOptions](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/#watchoptionspoll)*

---

If you are having the same issue with `nodemon` in a back-end Node.js project, you can use the `--legacy-watch` flag (short `-L`) which starts polling too.

```
npm exec nodemon -- --legacy-watch --watch src src/main.js
```

or in package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  "serve": "nodemon --legacy-watch --watch src src/main.js"
}
```

*documentation: [nodemon legacy watch](https://github.com/remy/nodemon#application-isnt-restarting)*

Answer (score 1):

If you use linux then you don't need to use `CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true`

Comment: I would be highly interested in the answer to "Why?".

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was running the docker run command in a Git bash command line (on Windows) and the hot reloading was not working. Using react-script v5.0.0, setting `WATCHPACK_POLLING=true` in the `.env` file and running the docker run command in **PowerShell** worked.

`docker run -it --rm -v ${PWD}:/app -v /app/node_modules -p 3000:3000 -e CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true myapp`

Answer (score 0):

I had to debug my source with different node versions and various options mentioned above but none worked unfortunately, however the only solution was to properly map the container to host source and use the `WORKDIR` of the `Dockerfile` in the `docker-compose.json` file.

> Dockerfile

```js
### EBMBOOK'S SINGLE STAGE NODE VERSION 
FROM node:18.13-alpine

# Create a Virtual directory inside the docker image
WORKDIR /app

# install app dependencies - install will only be triggered if there are new changes in the package.*json files
COPY package.json /app/package.json
COPY package-lock.json /app/package-lock.json
RUN npm install

# copy app too
COPY ./ /app

EXPOSE 3000

# Deploy app for local development
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

And, in the docker-compose.json link back the source to WORKDIR and of course don't forget the environment `WATCHPACK_POLLING=true` either.

> docker-compose.json

```js
services:
  # frontend
  frontend:
    container_name: central.ebmbook
    restart: always
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ../../frontend
    volumes:
      - ../../frontend/src:/app/src
      - /app/node_modules
    environment:
      - WDS_SOCKET_HOST=127.0.0.1 
      - WATCHPACK_POLLING=true 
    networks:
      - public
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
      
    ....
```