# React application don't refresh until i change App.js

Tags: reactjs

I am a newbie in React, and learning it through various free material.

In development mode, I am trying to create a simple website with header footer & body using components for each in App.js

The problem is while I change my code in Header OR Footer OR Body, the browser doesn't update its content even if i hard refresh the browser.

the only way to update the screen is if i make some changes in App.js file.
then it'll reflect all the changes i made.

Created using `npm install –g create-react-app` && `create-react-app my-app`
and started creating Header footer component inside App.js

How to solve this, apparently react is not detecting changes until App.js changes.

Comment: Restart the bundler, whenever you add new files

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly restarting bundler manually doesn't make sense. OP is expecting hot reloading to work seamlessly for all file changes and not only App.js

Comment: Sharing a little bit of details of your components is good to have. Though I already faced similar issue and figured out the point of problem. Try that out, it mostly worked for all of my colleagues.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Apparently, there is no inbuild react watcher to look out & include/consider newly added files.
So each time i am adding some new component in a new file, i need to `npm start`

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be some issue with `Chowkidar`. Please add `CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true` to your run script in `package.json`. Example below:

```
 "start": "CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true react-scripts start"
```

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to answer this without looking your code. 
Although one thing may be possible that you would not call header/footer/body component in app.js.
Please show code so that we can figure out problems.

Answer (score -1):

You might need to instantiate both the Header and The Footer in App.js!

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. This doesn't answer the original question. Please read [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) section to form a better answer.