# rollup.js live reload not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, docker, rollupjs

I'm building a react application with Rollup.js and trying to use live reload for better DX.
I install all packages and everything looks fine on the first run.

When I try to update my source code, the bundle is rebuilt & the page is refreshed but the changes do not appear in the compiled JS. If I end the process and restart again, the changes appeared.

rollup.config.ts attached below:

```
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';
import replace from '@rollup/plugin-replace';
import url from './renderer/rollupImageAssetsUrl';
import rollupUrl from '@rollup/plugin-url';
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser';
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';
import dts from 'rollup-plugin-dts';
import svgr from '@svgr/rollup';
import type { RollupOptions } from 'rollup'
import serve from 'rollup-plugin-serve';
import livereload from 'rollup-plugin-livereload';

const devConfig : RollupOptions = {
  input: './template/index.tsx',
  output: {
    file: './template/build/index.js',
    format: 'iife'
  },
  plugins: [
    replace({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify( 'production' ),
      CLASS_TYPE : process.env.CLASS_TYPE ? JSON.stringify(process.env.CLASS_TYPE) : JSON.stringify(`oocss`)
    }),
    resolve({
      browser: true,
      dedupe: ['react', 'react-dom'],
    }),
    typescript({
      tsconfig: './renderer/tsconfig.json',
      declaration: false,
      paths : {
        "component-library/style-library" : ["./../src/index.ts"]
      }
    }),
    commonjs(),
    url({
      fileName: 'images/[name][extname]',
      exclude: ['**/src/Icons/**/**.svg'],
      limit: 0,
      preserveImports: true
    }),
    rollupUrl({
      include: ['**/src/Icons/**/**.svg']
    }),
    svgr({
      icon: true,
      replaceAttrValues : {
        "#000" : "currentColor",
        "black" : "currentColor",
        "#000000" : "currentColor"
      },
      svgProps: {
        'pointerEvents' : 'none',
      }
    }),
    serve({
      contentBase: './template',
      host: '0.0.0.0',
      port: '3002',
    }),
    livereload({
      port: 3003,
      delay: 200
    }),
  ],
  watch: {
    buildDelay: 500,
    clearScreen: true
  }
}

export default devConfig;
```

Attached with my Docker Setting:

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  builder:
    container_name: style_library_package_builder_dev
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker_images/builder/Dockerfile
    image: style-library-package-builder:v0.2.0
    ports:
      - "3002:3002"
      - "3003:3003"
    environment:
      - "TZ=Asia/Tokyo"
      - "CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true"
      - "WATCHPACK_POLLING=true"
    volumes:
      - ./app/.storybook:/var/app/builder/.storybook
      - ./app/renderer:/var/app/builder/renderer
      - ./app/utils:/var/app/builder/utils
      - ./app/template:/var/app/builder/template
      - ./app/package.json:/var/app/builder/package.json
      - ./app/rollup.config.ts:/var/app/builder/rollup.config.ts
      - ./app/rollup.config.dev.ts:/var/app/builder/rollup.config.dev.ts
      - ./app/tsconfig.json:/var/app/builder/tsconfig.json
      - ./app/webpack.config.style.ts:/var/app/builder/webpack.config.style.ts
      - ./app/yarn.lock:/var/app/builder/yarn.lock
      - ./app/.babelrc.json:/var/app/builder/.babelrc.json
      - ./component-library/style-library/builder/src:/var/app/builder/src
      - ./component-library/style-library/builder/assets:/var/app/builder/assets
      - ./component-library/style-library/builder/stories:/var/app/builder/stories
      - ./component-library/style-library/builder/config:/var/app/builder/config
      - ./component-library/style-library/lib:/var/app/lib
      - ./component-library/style-library/package.json:/var/app/package.json
      - ./component-library/package.json:/var/package.json
      - ./component-library/docs:/var/docs
      - /var/app/builder/node_modules
    tty: true
    privileged: true
    secrets:
      - host_ssh_key
secrets:
  host_ssh_key:
    file: ${KEY}
```

I'm running rollup.js in a Docker Container (w/ image node:18-alpine3.15).
Is there any causes that you can think of about this behavior?
Any help are appreciated.

Tried `CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true` and `rollup.watch.chokidar.usePolling = true` but no luck

Edit :
I've tried to edit the images it seems that the update in images reflect in watch mode.
But when I update the Typescripts file, still no luck occur:(
New bundle is generated but the changes are not included.
Will there be issue in the @rollup/typescript plugin with watch mode?

Comment: A Docker container has an isolated filesystem, and a front-end application can't use Docker features like cross-container networking.  Would it be easier to use Node directly on your host system here?

Comment: The project is using Bitbucket Pipeline for CI/CD so Docker is preferred.

Comment: Your CI system won't do live reloading and I'm guessing you don't want the very large quantity of `volumes:` mounts to build a reusable image; these will be different setups no matter what.  It's fine to use a local Node for development, and a Docker-based environment for deployment.

Comment: This project is using puppeteer and sharp which is not having a compatible setting between my host system (Window) and the Docker container (Alpine) :( The debugging process between the two OS system is much more difficult than with Docker. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 2):

After one day of trying, I finally found out that there is a problem with `@rollup/plugin-typescript`(v11.1.1) when using watch mode of Rollup.JS.
I've modified my rollup.config.ts and changed my Typescript transpiler from  `@rollup/plugin-typescript` to `@rollup/plugin-babel`, everything works perfectly.

Attached with my current settings for anyone come to this problem:

```
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';
import replace from '@rollup/plugin-replace';
import url from './renderer/rollupImageAssetsUrl';
import rollupUrl from '@rollup/plugin-url';
import svgr from '@svgr/rollup';
import type { RollupOptions } from 'rollup'
import serve from 'rollup-plugin-serve';
import livereload from 'rollup-plugin-livereload';
import html from '@rollup/plugin-html';
import { babel } from '@rollup/plugin-babel';

const devConfig : RollupOptions = {
  cache: false,
  input: './template/index.tsx',
  output: {
    file: './build/index.js',
    format: 'iife'
  },
  plugins: [
    replace({
      preventAssignment: true,
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify( 'production' ),
      CLASS_TYPE : process.env.CLASS_TYPE ? JSON.stringify(process.env.CLASS_TYPE) : JSON.stringify(`oocss`)
    }),
    resolve({
      browser: true,
      dedupe: ['react', 'react-dom'],
    }),
    typescript({
      cacheDir: './build/cache',
      tsconfig: './renderer/tsconfig.json',
      declaration : true,
      outDir : './build/types',
      emitDeclarationOnly: true,
      noForceEmit: true,
      paths : {
        "component-library/style-library" : ["./../src/index.ts"]
      }
    }),
    babel({
      exclude: "**/node_modules/**",
      presets: ["@babel/preset-env","@babel/preset-react","@babel/preset-typescript"],
      extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"],
    }),
    commonjs(),
    url({
      fileName: 'images/[name][extname]',
      exclude: ['**/src/Icons/**/**.svg'],
      limit: 0,
      preserveImports: true
    }),
    rollupUrl({
      include: ['**/src/Icons/**/**.svg']
    }),
    svgr({
      icon: true,
      replaceAttrValues : {
        "#000" : "currentColor",
        "black" : "currentColor",
        "#000000" : "currentColor"
      },
      svgProps: {
        'pointerEvents' : 'none',
      }
    }),
    html(),
    serve({
      contentBase: './build',
      host: '0.0.0.0',
      port: '3002',
    }),
    livereload({
      port: 3003,
      delay: 500
    })
  ],
  watch: {
    chokidar: {
      usePolling: true
    },
    buildDelay: 500
  }
}

export default () => {
  return devConfig;
};
```

I still left `@rollup/plugin-typescript` here for type checking and path alias.
Will report this later in Github issue.

Answer (score 1):

In your docker yml configuration file do you have below setting :

`CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true`

You can refer to the below for more details:
[Live reload React with Docker](https://medium.com/@chavezharris/live-reload-with-docker-and-react-3d6de03920af)

Comment: Also see for example [Running development server with create-react-app inside of a docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44643045/running-development-server-with-create-react-app-inside-of-a-docker-container/44643246#44643246).

Comment: I have this in my docker settings, the rebuilt is triggered but no updates is included in the new bundle